# Magento downgrade 2.4 to 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4

[image]

Trying to downgrade Magento from version 2.4 using PHP 7.4 to Magento 2.3.x

I followed Magento docs to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of 2.3.x are you downgrading to?
Looks like your php version is too new for dependencies that is required on 2.3.x.

You can set your apache server to use a lower version of PHP.
Then the composer update should go through.

Sometimes your just running on a newer version of the dependency(ie php-cs-fixer) you can just run the update with --ignore-platform-reqs and it will still go through.
This is risky as the newer version could of updated something that breaks it.

I would downgrade your PHP to a version that is compatible with 2.3.5 or whatever version your going to.

Comment: 2.3.x really as the main reason for downgrade was 2.4 was too new for some plugins, should've though about this before.
The solution we took was to completely remove the 2.4 instance and add new 2.3 installation.

The PHP was the main cause of the errors experienced.

Comment: I just finished my 2.4 upgrade on my production site. I was holding out for a few of my plugins that finally updated. I really wanted the built in In-Store-Pickup module. So let me know if I can help more. (Also marking as answer would be great!)